# Could not change the index of combo SWT

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I am initializing the combo box with following values {1,2,3} and am binding it using the following property

```
IObservableList itemsCImpactObserveWidget = WidgetProperties.items().observe(cImpact);
        IObservableList impactComboModelObserveList = BeanProperties.list("impactCombo").observe(model);
        bindingContext.bindList(itemsCImpactObserveWidget, impactComboModelObserveList, null, null);

    //
    IObservableValue observeSingleSelectionIndexCImpactObserveWidget = WidgetProperties.singleSelectionIndex().observe(cImpact);
    IObservableValue impactIndexModelObserveValue = BeanProperties.value("impactIndex").observe(model);
    bindingContext.bindValue(observeSingleSelectionIndexCImpactObserveWidget, impactIndexModelObserveValue, null, null);
```

and using the following method

```
public List<String> getImpactCombo(){
    List<String> impactValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(impactMap != null && impactMap.size() > 0)
        impactValues.addAll(impactMap.values());
    return impactValues;
}
```

The problem is whenever I select a value from the combo box , it always throw an exception and gives the message "Could not change the index of impactIndex"

Comment: What is `model` and what methods does it have to deal with `impactIndex`?

Comment: model is a class which has all the bean properties methods like getImpactIndex() and getImpactCombo().  impactindex is the combo index for the combo "cImpact"

Comment: The error sounds like there is a problem with model so you need to show us the actual code.

Comment: Could you please take alook in this bug where I have added the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182634/empty-entry-in-the-swt-combo?noredirect=1#comment56111594_34182634  .